# Adding checkbox inside a listview in dhtmlx

Tags: dhtmlx

How can i add check box inside combo box within the grid view.

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - it impossible, but they have similar editor type - "clist", check 
http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/01_cell_types/09_pro_excell_extra.html

Answer (score 0):

You can outside the grid view, like [this link](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxForm/samples/09_extra/02_combo_with_checkboxes.html) suggest (from the official dhtmlx forums).

But inside the grid **you cannot**.

The [closest answer I found](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=8322) on the official dhtmlx forums said:

> There is no special integration of combo with checkboxes and dhtmlxgrid. 
>   "combo" column type purposed to be used with plain combobox mode only. 
>   Technically it possible to change it , so it will render as list with checkboxes, but checked values will not be accessible through grid's API

I hope this answer could help you. If not, you should ask the dhtmlx team directly, as it does not seem to be possible without imperfect workarounds.